# Control Key Output to Application with Focus

Tags: c#, hook

I'm wanting to capture what is being typed and release it at a slower rate. In other words, if someone is typing at 100 wpm, I want the text they are typing to only appear at a rate of 60 wpm.

I've been heavily basing my code off of [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx).

`CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);` is what determines if a key appears on the application. I've tried making a custom class like this:

```
public class KeyOutput
{
    public int vkcode;
    public int nCode;
    public IntPtr wParam;
    public IntPtr lParam;
    public KeyOutput(int in_vkcode, int in_code, IntPtr in_wParam, IntPtr in_lParam)
    {
        vkcode = in_vkcode;
        nCode = in_code;
        wParam = in_wParam;
        lParam = in_lParam;
    }
    public int Getvkcode
    {
        get
        {
            return vkcode;
        }
    }
    public int Getcode
    {
        get
        {
            return nCode;
        }
    }
    public IntPtr GetwParam
    {
        get
        {
            return wParam;
        }
    }
    public IntPtr GetlParam
    {
        get
        {
            return lParam;
        }
    }
}
```

I did it in hopes that by saving nCode, wParam, lParam I could simply call `CallNextHookEx` and it would display the character. When I tried to loop through the items in my `List<KeyOutput>` it would only display the last character that was pressed and none of the rest.

I've modified `HookCallback` like so (it currently displays text as they are typing it):

```
private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
            KeyOutput key = new KeyOutput(vkCode, nCode, wParam, lParam);
            listout.Add(key);
            Console.WriteLine((Keys)vkCode);
        }

        if (listout.Count == 8)
        {
            foreach (KeyOutput key in listout)
            {
                Console.WriteLine((Keys)key.Getvkcode);
                CallNextHookEx(_hookID, key.Getcode, key.GetwParam, key.GetlParam);
            }
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
```

`if(listout.Count == 8)` is arbitrary and servers no purpose other than testing.

Thank you for any help you may have!

Comment: This is definitely the strangest feature request I've seen this year.  Just use Thread.Sleep() in the hook callback.

Comment: I tried that and it works! I wanted to do it with `CallNextHookEx`, but I supposed that would be too difficult.